# C++ derived class and virtual destructor

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012

Please have a look at the simple code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class semi_shape_1 {
public:
    void output() { cout <<" semi_shape_1 works fine.\n"; }
    virtual ~semi_shape_1();

protected:
    semi_shape_1(){ output();}
};

class test_semiShape_1 : public semi_shape_1 {
};


int main()
{
    test_semiShape_1 ts1;
    return 0;
}
```

The `semi_shape_1` is a bass class and the `test_semiShape_1` has been derived from it.
When I run the code, I get two errors as follows:

**Error1**  *error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall semi_shape_1::~semi_shape_1(void)" (??1semi_shape_1@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall test_semiShape_1::~test_semiShape_1(void)" (??1test_semiShape_1@@UAE@XZ) C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj*

**Error2**  *error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals  C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1*

What is the problem with my code please?
Machine: Windows 7.
IDE: visual studio 2012.

Comment: Just change `virtual ~semi_shape_1();` to `virtual ~semi_shape_1() { }`.  `unresolved external symbol` means some variable or function that's declared in the program during compilation isn't actually found *defined* at link time, so the "pieces" of the program can't be put together to form a whole.  Admittedly, when you've got a one-file program all the terminology might be more confusing than helpful....

Comment: You have already researched what this error means in general, or? Please also note that you don't get to the "run the code" part, your error is from the linking stage of compilation! BTW: If you had tried to reduce this code, you would have found that the `virtual` on the destructor is completely irrelevant!

Comment: @TonyD. Thank you very much for your valuable explanations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implementation of the base class's destructor. The compiler will implicitly create one if you do not provide a definition, but since you provided one, you must also provide the implementation. Tony's comment has the answer:

> Just change virtual ~semi_shape_1(); to virtual ~semi_shape_1() { }

Comment: Thank you. I make your answer an `answer` soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a definition for the destructor.

```
virtual ~semi_shape_1() {}
```

or in C++11

```
virtual ~semi_shape_1() = default;
```

or you can make it pure if `semi_shape_1` is supposed to be an abstract class, but don't forget to define it outside the class definition:

```
virtual ~semi_shape_1() = 0;
// ...
semi_shape_1::~semi_shape_1() = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a destructor but not implemented it.